# Simple test with Command fails

Tags: windows, rust, cmd

I'm at the beginning of a beginning Rust book. Coded the "Hello World" and it compiled and works as expected. The next example in the book gives an example of adding tests to the project. It used the command "ls" which lets me know the author is using Linux. I changed it to "dir" for Windows - however, the test fails.

Here is the code I'm using in my `cli.rs` file with the test code:

```
use std::process::Command;

#[test]
fn runs() {
  let mut cmd = Command::new("dir");
  let res = cmd.output();
  assert!(res.is_ok());
}
```

I used `cargo test --test cli` with the expectation of seeing at the end, "test runs ... ok"

Instead, I get a failure result. Here is the complete text:

```
  Compiling test01 v0.1.0 (D:\GoogleDrive\prog\rust\test01)
    Finished test [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 2.77s
     Running tests\cli.rs (target\debug\deps\cli-17383a3960882a20.exe)

running 1 test
test runs ... FAILED

failures:

---- runs stdout ----
thread 'runs' panicked at tests\cli.rs:9:3:
assertion failed: res.is_ok()
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace


failures:
    runs

test result: FAILED. 0 passed; 1 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out; finished in 0.01s

error: test failed, to rerun pass `--test cli`
```

Why is this test failing?

Further possibly relevant information:

- My OS: Windows 10
- Rust version: 1.73.0
- Editor: Visual Studio Code

Comment: I'm not logged into windows right now, but I'm pretty sure `dir` isn't an executable but rather a shell built-in. `ls` is an executable which can be run with `Command`, but `Command` isn't running the `cmd.exe` and therefore doesn't have access to its built-in commands.

Comment: Assertiing that res.is_ok cannot give you the reasonof the failing. Have you tried to add a `println!("{:#?}", res)` before the assertion ?

Comment: To expand a little: [`Command`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/process/struct.Command.html) is used to run programs. `dir` is (AFAIK) not a program on Windows, instead it's a feature of the `cmd.exe` command line, so `Command` cannot run it. On Unix-like (Linux, MacOS, etc.) `ls` typically _is_ provided as an executable, so it can be run in this way.

Comment: It would also be useful if you linked to the example you're working from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, `dir` is an *internal* command of the `cmd.exe` shell.

You should try something like this:

```rust
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    let mut cmd = Command::new("cmd.exe");
    cmd.arg("/C");
    cmd.arg("dir");
    match cmd.output() {
        Ok(output) => {
            let utf8_txt = String::from_utf8_lossy(&output.stdout);
            println!("output:\n{}", utf8_txt);
        }
        Err(e) => {
            println!("ERROR: {:?}", e);
        }
    }
}
```

This launches a process running the program `cmd.exe`.
The [argument `/C`](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) tells this command interpreter to consider the following arguments as a command to be executed (as is it was input interactively in the terminal).

Comment: This works - and being a complete novice with Rust - I have zero understanding of the nuances. (Like, I've not seen the "match" keyword yet, though I can guess from the context here what it's used for.) But, of course, in trying to stick with code I've seen about Command on the Internet, I altered your code and used this:

  let mut cmd = CoCommand::new("cmd.exe")
    .arg("/C")
    .arg("dir");

Which failed with "temporary value is freed at the end of this statement."

So, of course, I just used your code as-is, which works.

Thank you very much.